# To call method using super in mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How to call method using super keyword in Mockito? Code is given as below in snippet:

```
 @Override
protected void doExecute()
{
    //only show port context menu in edit mode
    ICommandContext commandContext = getCommandContext();
    if( commandContext instanceof ContextMenuCommandContext )
    {
        ContextMenuCommandContext contextMenuContext = (ContextMenuCommandContext) commandContext;
        if( !contextMenuContext.getRelationsContext().isAuthoringMode() )
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    super.doExecute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,
Consider your derived class name,

```
class BaseClass {  
    public void doExecute() {...}  
}

public ChildClass extends BaseClass {  

     @override
      public void doExecute(){  
        //some codes    
        super.doExecute();
    }  
}
```

I assume your code is something like this,

```
 @Test
public void testdoExecute() {
    DerivedClassName cn= Mockito.cn(new DerivedClassName());

    // Prevent/stub logic in super.doExecute();
    Mockito.doNothing().when((BaseClassName)cn).doExecute();

    // When
    cn.doExecute();

    // Then
    verify(cn).load();
}
```

Comment: please consider name your class in which your method is present. as you have not posted in question

Comment: in above method cn is undefined variable for Mockito.cn(new DerivedClassName())

Comment: suppose doExecute is protected in baseclass then can we execute doExecute method in Test class

Comment: yes you can do that you need to just put both baseclass and testclass in same package. But  best way to test private/protected method is using reflection.